# How to parse a file containing html using JSOUP?

Tags: java, web, jsoup

I have files containing HTML  and I am trying to parse that file and then tokenise the text of  the body.
I achieve this through:

```
docs = JSOUP.parse("myFile","UTF-8","");
System.out.println(docs.boy().text());
```

The above codes work fine but the problem is TEXT that is present outside of html tags without any tag is also printed as part of the body tags.
**I need to find a way to stop this text outside of HTML tags from being read
Help this is a time sensitive question !**

Answer (score 0):

You can select and remove unwanted elements in your document.

```
 doc.select("body > :matchText").remove();
```

The above statement will remove all text-nodes, that are direct children of the body-element. The :matchText selector is rather new, so please make sure to use a somehow recent version of JSoup (1.11.3 definitely works, but 1.10.2 not).

Find more infos on the selector syntax on https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax